# Angular ui-router parameter causes conflicts with other states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Just to give some context, I have an Angular application with several separate modules. I am working with ui-router to provide routing to these modules, and I want to use the names of the modules in the URLs. In my Angular app config block I have defined a state for both module1 and module2 with a parameter on each like so:

```
.state('module1', {
    url: '/:module_name',
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/module1/views/index.html',
    controller: 'someCtrl'
})

.state('module2', {
    url: '/:module_name',
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/module2/views/index.html',
    controller: 'someOtherCtrl'
})
```

I also have a few links that should take me to the home page of each module.

Naturally, the problem is that the first state will catch all of the rest of my module2 routes, since their URLs all have the same form:

http://localhost:3000/#/module1

http://localhost:3000/#/module2/users

http://localhost:3000/#/module2/books

and so on. I can see how the order that we define the stats is important, but I can't seem to come up with a way to be able to have the module name as a state parameter (this is important since I need it in the corresponding controllers to distinguish from which module an operation is coming from) and avoid this hierarchy problem altogether.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case ui-router will not know which route your are pointing to as they are exactly the same. You would either have to hardcode the module name(assuming there are only a few):

```
.state('module1', {
    url: '/module1',
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/module1/views/index.html',
    controller: 'someCtrl'
})

.state('module2', {
    url: '/module2',
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/module2/views/index.html',
    controller: 'someOtherCtrl'
})

.state('module2', {
    url: '/module2/users',
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/module2/views/users.html',
    controller: 'someOtherCtrl'
})

.state('module2', {
    url: '/module2/books',
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/module2/views/books.html',
    controller: 'someOtherCtrl'
})
```

or dynamically inject the html based on the module number

```
.state('module', {
    url: '/module/:moduleId',
    templateUrl:
        function (stateParams){
            return '/app/modules/module' + stateParams.moduleId + '/views/index.html';
        }
    controller: 'someOtherCtrl'
})
```

so now to hit module one the path looks like this

http://localhost:3000/#/module/1

Comment: That's awesome. I used the dynamic injection option and it's working perfectly. Just what I needed, thanks!